# Сhanging number of buttons with different functions in Header-component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I would like to have a Header-component but with varying number of buttons and different functions that those buttons can trigger, for example, "visit about page", "trigger vuex action A" on home page and "visit home page", "trigger vuex action B" on about page.

What is the right way to achieve this in Vue?

Comment: You could use slots https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html

Comment: Should the button be a separate component?

Comment: It can be a simplet button or any other component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic example using Vue [Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html), [Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) and [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/).

```
<my-menu>
  <menu-item header>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </menu-item>
  <menu-item @click="gotoAboutUs()">
    About Us
  </menu-item>
</my-menu>
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const MyMenu = {
  template: `<div class="ui menu"><slot></slot></div>` 
}

const MenuItem = {
  props: {
    header: { type: Boolean },
    right: { type: Boolean }
  },
  template: `<div :class="['item', header ? 'header' : '', right ? 'right' : '']"><slot></slot></div>` 
}

const App = {
  components: {
    MyMenu, MenuItem
  },
  methods: {
   gotoAboutUs: () => alert('About Us')
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.5.0/dist/semantic.min.css">
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<my-menu>
  <menu-item header>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
  </menu-item>
  <menu-item @click="gotoAboutUs()">
    About Us
  </menu-item>
  <menu-item right>
     <div class="ui action input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Navigate to...">
      <div class="ui button">Go</div>
    </div>
  </menu-item>
</my-menu>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```